# MeteorJS Meteor call when does it becomes stressful in the server

Tags: meteor

Just two question about meteor call, is it a mortal sin in meteor to use Meteor.call many times like 10 to 50 times? If so is there a limit to it? Thank you.

Comment: A `Meteor.call` from front-end to back-end is more-or-less same as a REST API call, as far as I understand. And usually, with API calls, too many of them are avoided to reduce network overhead. So, I think it would be prudent to limit the number of calls, or rethink the the API call altogether.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen I see, understood, I did some tests using Meteor Dev Tools and found out that per meteor call cost me 82 bit per request so it seems I can call up to more than 100 depending on the amount of data but I will try to avoid it too many requests. Thank you. :)

Comment: You could also try combining multiple API calls into one. It's a matter of how to design the API call.